# Flex to ignore side margin when centering elements

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am having trouble getting flex to center elements (with margin) when it wraps.

It looks perfect when the screen is wide
[image]

But it is not centering it when it wraps (because of the right-margin of the first button)
[image]

Here is my code: https://jsfiddle.net/dLz7120k/2/

```
footer { display: flex; flex-flow: row wrap; justify-content: center; }
button { margin: 0 20px 10px 0; }
button:last-child { margin-right: 0; }
```

Is there any way to make it ignore the right-margin of the first button when it wraps?
(I don't want to change the spacing between the buttons, or add unnecessary margins before/after the first/last button)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Split* the margins *between* the `button` elements - make it `margin: 5px 10px` for both so that you can *retain* 20px between the buttons horizontally and 5px between them vertically when they wrap.

To avoid the *wrapping a bit too early*, you can use *negative margins* on the `footer` container element to adjust for the margins causing this *early wrapping* (thanks to [LGSon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2827823/lgson) for pointing out this trick). See modified demo below:

```css
* {
  font-size: 18px;
}
#modal {
  margin: 10%;
  padding: 15px;
  width: 50%;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
p {
  text-align: center;
}

footer {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 0 -20px; /* extend by this amount on both sides */
}
button {
  margin: 5px 10px; 
}
```

```html
<div id='modal'>
  <p>Some text and some paragraph</p>
  <footer>
    <button>Cancel</button>
    <button>Continue</button>
  </footer>
</div>
```

Comment: This adds unnecessary margins on the left and right buttons so the buttons will wrap sooner when it doesn't actually need to wrap yet. I'm trying to avoid this.

Comment: I can't see a way out until its possible to *detect* wrapping in CSS, but that is actually not possible

Comment: @Aximili and kukkuz: There is on trick one can use, using negative margins and with that avoid a too early wrap [fiddle sample](https://jsfiddle.net/p8fby1mg/3/) ... I decided to delete my answer showing that, so feel free to add it to yours.

Comment: well, you shouldn't have deleted it, *that* answer should have been here :) I always forget about the *negative margins* hack, being active in SO always augments my work and knowledge, only a minor hiccup for an year when I wasn't well and didn't have time for SO...  Anyway I learned my first CSS lessons from here and from then on I've not looked back, I've just loved it :)

Comment: Then just add it :)

Comment: @LGSon That is the solution! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You have to write `@media` style for the width of the screen when it wraps and remove margin-right in there.

E.g.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  button {
    margin: 0 0 10px;
  }
}
```

Comment: I can't use this because the button text is dynamic and I don't know when it's gonna wrap

Comment: I understand this problem. As a workaround (and good design) button width's can be set to a fixed size. 

Also in this particular case you can use **left** or **sides** margin instead of right and it won't have that bugs.

Comment: ah, you're centering them. Correct then.

Comment: So there is 2 ways that I can see now: Fixed width buttons or side margins.